# Azure Windows server 2019 no inbound connection

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-update, azure-vm

I have an Azure Windows Server 2019 which we deployed some windows update yesterday and now we can't connect to machine.
I checked there is no inbound connection but outbound is working fine.
I also disabled the all firewall profiles but the issue still persists.
I can't connect to Vm using neither RDP nor PS remoting , can only run ps commands from portal.
The RDP is running and listening and I can test connection locally .

I don't have any anti virus installed and since firewall is disabled what else can block the connection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems registry key was changed
I deleted AllowLocalIPsecPolicyMerge,DisableUnicastResponsesToMulticastBroadcast and AllowLocalPolicyMerge from below reg keys and started working

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile'
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PrivateProfile'
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile'
```